# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt: invalid salt Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting this error when i try to create new User, like this

```
>> User.create(:email=>"nandosousafr@gmail.com", :password => "hello")
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt: invalid salt
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:56:in `hash_secret'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:161:in `create'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:110:in `password_digest'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:37:in `password='
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `send'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `assign_attributes'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:495:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
from (irb):3
```

> >

Gemfile

```
require 'rbconfig'
HOST_OS = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem "compass-rails"  
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'less'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.1"

gem "rest-client"

gem "haml", ">= 3.1.6"
gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.4", :group => :development

gem "devise", ">= 2.1.0"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.7"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.1.0"
gem "therubyracer", :group => :assets, :platform => :ruby
gem "simple_form"
gem "will_paginate", ">= 3.0.3"
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.7"
gem "rdiscount"
gem 'oily_png'
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

i've googled and i found a article that lead me to put config.encryptor = :sha1, instead of config.encryptor = :bcrypt, but the problem wasn't solved..

anyone?

Comment: I assume you have `devise.rb` in `your_app/config/intializers` folder?

Comment: yes.. i've tried to use sha1 instead brypt. but nothing..

Comment: could you paste your User.rb and your Gemfile

Comment: Try uninstalling your `bcrypt-ruby` gem and installing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried reinstalling the `bcrypt-ruby` gem?

```
  # Remove all versions of bcrypt-ruby
  sudo gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby

  # Install the latest version 
  sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling bcrypt-ruby hasn't worked for me.

The bug [got fixed](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/commit/f1621d686b6c41ae4157667b3f76735cfbbc60e5) in **bcrypt-ruby >= 3.1.10**, but Rails 3.2 locked on **bcrypt-ruby 3.0.x**.

Solution would be to either:

- move to newer Rails version (>=4)
- use older Ruby version (2.1.x)
- fork [my changes](https://github.com/yukas/rails/tree/bump-bcrypt-ruby-version-to-3-1) and keep up with security updates by yourself (since currently Rails 3.2 supports only severe security updates)

Comment: bcrypt-ruby 3.1.9 does not exist as a gem,

Comment: Yep, it is not released yet, unfortunately. You can use it straight from Github: `gem "bcrypt-ruby", github: "codahale/bcrypt-ruby", ref: "1f9184a"`. Link to the commit: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/commit/1f9184a8df2b90fa02d01a32a364eefc9072e1b9