# Rails: BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt: invalid salt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salt, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

Loosely following Ryan Bates's [How I Test](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?view=asciicast) Railscast to implement sending an email confirmation token to users when they sign up.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  strip_attributes except: [:password, :password_confirmation]
  ...

  def send_email_confirmation
    generate_token(:email_token)
    self.email_token_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.email_confirmation(self).deliver
  end

  private
    def generate_token(column)
      begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
    end
end
```

This is failing (in feature specs and when manually clicking through sign-up process) with:

```
Failures:

  1) UserPages sign up with valid information should create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
     BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt:
       invalid salt
     # ./app/models/user.rb:70:in `send_email_confirmation'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in `create'
     # ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:165:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:165:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried reinstalling bcrypt gem (as suggested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579696/bcrypterrorsinvalidsalt-invalid-salt-devise) even though it was Devise related and I'm not using Devise): `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby` and then `gem install bcrypt-ruby` but to no avail. ideas?

Comment: Line 70 is the call to `generate_token`?

Comment: Line 70 is actually the call to `save!`…which leads me to wonder if a circular error may be causing this…

Comment: nope, doesn't appear to be circular...

Comment: strange thing is that from the Rails Console I can walk through each step of `send_email_confirmation` manually and `save!` without a problem!?!

Comment: Turns out `strip_attributes` was the problem. Adding `strip_attributes except: [:password, :password_confirmation, :password_digest]` seems to have fixed things.

Answer (score 0):

Gem **`strip_attributes`** is responsible for such behavior.

#### Solution

Exclude `:password_digest` attribute from stripping like below:

```
strip_attributes except: [:password_digest]
```

Answer (score 0):

We hit this error and it was because **we were trying to perform a *write* operation in a k8s pod that only had *read* access to the database**.

I'm sure this isn't the answer to the original question, but I came across this question when we were trying to figure out what was causing this error for us so I wanted to share.